# Why waitforexit dont work for all exe with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Why some of the applications work with waitforexit but some doesn't work like notepad works fine bit dcomcnfg.exe doesn't what is the reason

**Has edited the app.manifest to run this application with admin right**

**Application is debuged for any cpu**

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace prchk
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Method();
        }
        public void Method()
        {
            Process prcs = new Process();
            prcs.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\dcomcnfg.exe";
            //p.StartInfo.Arguments = argu;
            prcs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            prcs.Start();
            prcs.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("Exited");
        }
    }
}
```

Here exited is showing before the application is exited
What i tried:

> 1> Has tried hasexited
>
> 2> Has tried useshellexecution = false

Is there any way to wait for the application to exit for this kind of applications?

Comment: `WaitForExit` do not wait for child process to exit.

Comment: So what can i do is there any solution?